# How to convert form values into json format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, visual-studio-2010

I am using Form. In my database data is stored in the `form{type:"input",name:"name",Label:"Login"}` I am using ajax function to get these values.

I want to convert this into `json` object format, How can I convert into json object format ?

Comment: are you are talking about getting values from database to a view in json format ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, how to get value from an action using an ajax function in a Json object fomat, below is the sample code for that.

Here I am making an ajax call to "GetData" action.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetData")';
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
data: { value: strId},

success: function (result) {
 // do what you want with result returned here in JSON format
}
});
```

**Update:** In the above success method, you can read JSON values as `result.type`, `result.name` and `result.Label`.

and here is the Action, which is returning JSON data

```
public ActionResult GetData(string id)
{
return Json(new {type="type", name="name", Label="Login"});
}
```

Comment: I want a json object to be declared in controller and i need to access that object in view but not accessing json values.

Comment: The above json code would be implemented in controller.is it possible to create json object in the controller,If possible how to create it

Comment: with this 'Json(new {type="type", name="name", Label="Login"});' I am creating JSON object in controller

Answer (score 0):

*From OP's comment,*

> Is it possible to create json object in the controller, If possible
>   how to create it?

You can try JSON.NET to create JSON objects easily in an MVC application.

For ex. you could do something like this in JSON.NET,

```
dynamic jsonObj = new JObject();
jsonObj.Name = "Mark";
jsonObj.Age = 29;

var jsonString = jsonObj.ToString(); // { "Name" : "Mark", "Age" : 29 }
```

You can also create json object from parsing a string,

```
   dynamic jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

You can download JSON.NET from [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).